# Is there a formula to index unique products of two integers in a 2D array?

Tags: products

I am working with a flattened 2D array $C$ of size $A = n \times m$ and trying to create another array $D$ of size $k$, which contains unique products of the indices from $C$, i.e., $C[i \times j]$, where $0 \leq i < n$ and $0 \leq j < m$. Note that $i \times j$ is the same as $j \times i$, hence some products overlap. The output array $D$ contains unique values of $C[i \times j]$ such that $D[u] = C[i \times j]$, where $u$ is a unique index for each unique product, and $k$ is the total number of these unique products.

Based on my observations for large sizes, $k \approx 0.25 \times A$. Currently, I'm using a map $h$ to store the relationship $h[i \times j] = u$ so that $D[u] = C[i \times j]$. However, the map becomes quite substantial in size for very large arrays (e.g., $2^{28}$).

Is there a known mathematical function or method to create an index for these unique products by a formula, instead of using a map? Specifically, I'm looking for a function that would take $i$ and $j$ as input and output $u$, such that $0 \leq u < k$.

**Update:**

A sample:

For $C$ = $[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]$ and $n$ = 2 and $m$ = 4 the combination of unique values would be $D$ = $[0, 1, 2, 3]$ and the $h$ map would be equal to $D$.

For $C$ = $[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]$ and $n$ = 3 and $m$ = 4, $D$ = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6] and so on.

indexes are $0$ based

Comment: could you give some examples of such C and D arrays, with how the indexing works? To me it isn't clear what is done.

Comment: If $0\le i \le n$ and $0\le j \le m$ then $(i,j)$ takes $(n+1)\times (m+1)$ values, instead of $n\times m$. Are you sure you want that? Shouldn't the indices begin from $1$?

Comment: hi, thanks for you review - indeed, let me fix

Comment: It seems to me the question is: if we multiply each of the numbers $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ by each of the numbers $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$, how many distinct products result, and how does the answer compare to $k=mn$? Is this correct? If so, the array $C$ is irrelevant (and $D$ isn't really needed as well). The answer is that the number of distinct products is eventually less than any constant times $k$—this is the famous (to number theorists anyway) [Erdös multiplication table problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663/distinct-numbers-in-multiplication-table).

Comment: @GregMartin Actually, this is needed to store and access twiddle factors for FFT computation. We need $w^{ij}$